# Elasticsearch 2.4: How to concatenate ANDs?

Tags: elasticsearch

This might seem trivial, and something that can be easily googled, but i couldn't find it:

On regular SQL, i can further refine a query by adding `{boolean operator} fieldX = valueY`. Indefinitely! How can i obtain the same result on elasticsearch 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the structure shown below, and add to the array of match or filter objects.

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title":   "Search"        }},
        { "match": { "content": "Elasticsearch" }}
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "status": "published" }},
        { "range": { "publish_date": { "gte": "2015-01-01" }}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: quick question, what if i have multiples must AND multiples must_not?

Comment: You can use them in the same query - for example, you could have must matching a term, then must_not using a range. In the example above, you would just have another object after the filter object, containing an array of must_not conditions